# Split sql results by category

Tags: php, mysql, split

I got some data from a database that I am returning, but at the moment it returns everything in one big list.

The data has a categoryname for every couple items. I would like to seperate every group of items that have a category assigned to it.

```
Example:

test1 (has category testing)
test2 (has category testing)
test3 (has category testing123)
```

These results just show into one big list, I would like the result to be like:

```
testing:
test1
test2

testing123:
test3
```

How do I do this?

My code as it is now (only relevant parts):

```
while ($row_items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_items)) {

        $checklist = '';
        if ($row_items['checkpoints'] != '') {
            $check = explode(',', $row_items['checkpoints']);
            foreach($check as $list) {
                $checklist .= '
                <li class="cataloguslist">
                    <i style="color:#e88f41;" class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true">
                </i> '.$list.'</li>'; 
            }
        }

        echo '
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portf">
          <a class="fancybox" href="../../catalogus/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'">
            <div class="gallery-item">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="../../catalogus_icons/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'.jpg" alt="" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>

                <div class="bottom-info" style="min-height:200px;">
                    <div class="name">'.$row_items['naam'].'</div>
                    <ul style="margin-left:35px;margin-top:10px;">'.$checklist.'</ul>
                    <a href="contact.php">
                        <button class="contact_button buttoncontact btn-primary" style="border-radius:2px;">
                            Vraag offerte aan
                            <span class="icon-mail-alt"></span>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                    <div class="contactlink">
                        <a href="contact.php">Neem contact op</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>';
    }
```

Every result has a `cat` row in the database, that connects to producten_cats (a table with `id` the same as `cat` and the category name in it aswell with tablerow name: `naam`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell where your category names lie from your code, so I can't give you a precise answer.

To split up your database resultset as you showed, do something like this, to detect when you get the first row with a new `category` value in your database resultset.

```
$previous_category = "---nothing---";
while ($row_items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_items)) {

    $category = $row_items['category'];
    if ( $category != $previous_category ) {
        $previous_category = $category;
        /* show category header, for example */
        echo '<h2>$category:</h2>';
    } 
    $checkpoints = $row_items['checkpoints'];
    /* show details, for example */
    echo '<p>$checkpoints</p>';
    }
```

For this sort of thing to work correctly, you need to use `ORDER BY category` in your query.

This kind of technique is generically known as *presentation-layer formatting.* It converts the tables of data presented by MySQL to a user-friendly layout.